# Set State inside method onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to set the state inside a method, i have a simple voting system (Yes or No) if you click **Yes** the state needs to be a string **up** and if you click **No** the state needs to be **down**

I am having trouble merging the method **voteHandler** and **setVote**

Here is my component :

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import {AnswerContext} from './AnswerWrapper';

const AnswerItem = (props) => {

    let indexPlus;

    const indexCount = (index) => {
        indexPlus = index;
        return indexPlus;
    }

    const { active, setActive } = useContext(AnswerContext)

    const [vote, setVote] = useState();

    const voteHandler = (e, index) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActive(index);
        setVote(""); // this might be "up" or "down"
        // I am sending this to a parent component
        props.onVote ({
            vote : vote,
            answerID : index
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index)}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index)}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AnswerItem;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the value when you bind the `onClick`:

```
<button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'up')}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
<button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index, 'down')}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
```

And use that in your `voteHandler`:

```
    const voteHandler = (e, index, value) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActive(index);
        setVote(value); // this might be "up" or "down"
        // I am sending this to a parent component
        props.onVote ({
            vote : vote,
            answerID : index
        })
    }
```

## Warning

When you do:

```
        setVote(value); // this might be "up" or "down"
        // I am sending this to a parent component
        props.onVote ({
            vote : vote,
            answerID : index
        })
```

You will not get the updated `vote` since `setState` is asynchronous. If you  want to call `props.onVote` on every `vote` and `active` change, use a `useEffect`:

```
const AnswerItem = (props) => {

    let indexPlus;

    const indexCount = (index) => {
        indexPlus = index;
        return indexPlus;
    }

    const { active, setActive } = useContext(AnswerContext)

    const [vote, setVote] = useState();
   
    useEffect(() => {
        props.onVote ({
            vote : vote,
            answerID : active
        })
    }, [vote, active])

    const voteHandler = (e, index) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActive(index);
        setVote("");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index)}>Yes <span>({props.ups !== null ? props.ups : 0 })</span></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, props.index)}>No <span>({props.downs !== null ? props.downs : 0 })</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add a localstorage so the user can only click once, if he decided yes he can't shoose again (yes or no)

Comment: I would recommend a global state management for that, or `Context API`, and once you get the value you can return inside the `voteHandler` depending on your flag. So `setState` for vote and active won't work, and `useEffect` won't run again.

Comment: Can you add it to the code?

Comment: That is another question, which is not clear to me right now. You can ask another question by clearly explaining what you want to achieve, and what you have tried, if you want.